# Set UI before one second of Synchronous HTTP Request in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, synchronous

As, Synchronous HTTPRequest call Works on Main UI Thread (and freezes it), I want to set my UI Completely(UI goes into "AS IT IS" state, as of now. So, It looks like my App got hanged) before one second of Synchronous Web Service Call.

Currently I am sending request using following:

`[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:myRequest returningResponse:&myResponse error:&myError]`

P.S. : I don't want to use Async Call or any other Public API for HTTP Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes you put your request in a method called myRequestMethod.

You really should be using a background thread like so:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myRequestMethod) withObject:nil];
```

But if you don't want to do it the right way, you can wait a second before starting your request with:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myRequestMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.f];
```